# Get Selected Option Of Multiple List of MatSelectionList - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material-6

Im looking for a solution for this:
I have this

```
 result = [
    {
      "roomsFloor": {
          "floor": {
            "floorName": "piso 1",
            "room": [{
              "roomNumber": "103"
            }]
          }
        }
    },
   {
      "roomsFloor": {
          "floor": {
            "floorName": "piso 2",
            "room": 
            [
              {
                "roomNumber": "104"
              },
                {
                "roomNumber": "105"
              }            
            ]
          }
        }
    },
  ]
```

Im using Angular Material 6 with MatExpanssionPanel, MatAcrodion, MatSelectionList for represent this data, but i need get an array with selected option for every Accordion

I try with this

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of result" hideToggle = "false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <mat-panel-title style="color: #44474B">
           <strong><p>{{item.roomsFloor.floor.floorName}}</p></strong>
       </mat-panel-title>
       <mat-panel-description>          
       </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
       <mat-selection-list #items (selectionChange)="handleSelection(items.selectedOptions)">
           <mat-list-option *ngFor="let roomDetail of item.roomsFloor.floor.room" [value]="roomDetail">
              <mat-icon mat-list-icon>meeting_room</mat-icon>
              <h4 mat-line>No. {{roomDetail.roomNumber}}</h4>
          </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </ng-template>                   
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

.TS component

```
   handleSelection(itemRoomSelected) {
        this.selectedRooms = itemRoomSelected.selected.map(item => item.value);
        console.log('selected room', this.selectedRooms);
    }
```

This method show me the selected item for accordion section opened but when open other item of accordion and select others item in the selection list, then the array is reset with new value from current accordion section.

What could be the solution, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us template driven forms to solve this issue.

Wrap your html in a form tag and define a template reference of whatever form name you need... in this example I just used `myForm` but it can be whatever you need.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
```

When using template driven forms you need to assign a name to the `mat-selection-list` so that it can create a FormControl to store the values... in this example I pass your `floorName` as that made the most sense...

- **Please note:** the square brackets around name [] for property binding... this is important.

  ```
  [name]="item.roomsFloor.floor.floorName"
  ```

Then pass your form values to your method on selection change.

```
(selectionChange)="handleSelection(myForm.value)"
```

This will result in an array of values from both accordions with the floorName as the parent key(s) passed to your method.

```
piso 1: Array(1)
0: {roomNumber: "103"}

piso 2: Array(2)
0: {roomNumber: "104"}
1: {roomNumber: "105"}
```

---

HTML

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of result" hideToggle = "false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <mat-panel-title style="color: #44474B">
           <strong><p>{{item.roomsFloor.floor.floorName}}</p></strong>
       </mat-panel-title>
       <mat-panel-description>          
       </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
       <mat-selection-list #items (selectionChange)="handleSelection(myForm.value)" [name]="item.roomsFloor.floor.floorName" ngModel>
           <mat-list-option *ngFor="let roomDetail of item.roomsFloor.floor.room" [value]="roomDetail">
              <mat-icon mat-list-icon>meeting_room</mat-icon>
              <h4 mat-line>No. {{roomDetail.roomNumber}}</h4>
          </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </ng-template>                   
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marshal this work for me!! Great Solution. Just i formated your Answer for only get one array with all selected items without the name of FormControl but was that i needed... regards man! thank again !